# Mainnet Api to generate new account?

Tags: wallet, mainnet, keosd, api

Using this api http://faucet.cryptokylin.io/create_account?testingaccoun2 it's possibile to generate new wallet whicch can be used on the testnet of crypto kylin.  I need same thing for the mainnet, is there any wrapper api to generate new wallet? or else it's possible for me to generate a keys offilline, but I don't know to import thtat to mainnet.  please help me with any one of that.

Answer (score 1):

Creating accounts and creating wallets are not the same thing. A wallet is a local store of keys, an account lives on the blockchain.

Creating an account on EOSIO blockchain requires resources and is not free. It is a one time expense. You need to own an account on EOSIO to create a new account.

There are some services which help you create an account,

Examples:

- [EOSLynx](https://eoslynx.com/) mobile wallet
- [eos-account-creator](https://eos-account-creator.com/) website

Answer (score 0):

EOS wallet creation(key generation) and account generation are two different process.
To create key pair

```
cleos wallet create --to-console
```

This will give you a private key and a public key. Using this key pair, you can create as much accounts as you want. As mentioned in the previous answer, you can use tools for creating your accounts.

- [EOS Toolkit](https://eostoolkit.io/account/create)
- [EOS Lynx](https://eoslynx.com) (from mobile)

For more details, please refer [eos documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/wallets)